# search not working in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, partials

i have 2 search fields in 2 different views. they both search for establishments and are identical except for styling.

one is in welcome/index.html.erb and works great.

the other is in a partial called _nav.html.erb and is called from application.html.erb and does not work at all.

do i need to pass something into the _nav partial for it to process the search form properly?

welcome/index.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag(establishments_path, method: "get") do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
          placeholder: "Enter the name of an eatery", class: "form-control" %>
      <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
    </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

_nav.html.erb

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <%= form_tag(establishments_path, method: "get") do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
          placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %></div>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
```

EstablishmentsController/index

```
def index
  if params[:search]
   @establishments = Establishment.search(params[:search].downcase).order("created_at ASC")
  else
    @establishments = Establishment.all.limit(25)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `form_tag` is already wrapped in a form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
#^^^^ Here
  <%= form_tag(establishments_path, method: "get") do %>
     #^^^^ and here again
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], 
          placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %></div>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

When you click on the submit tag, it submits the wrong form (the first one).

You should use it like this:

```
<%= form_tag(establishments_path, method: :get, class: 'navbar-form navbar-left', role: 'search') do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %></div>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```